# Time Complexity on string slicing operation in python 3

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

> Given a string s of length n, the slicing operation `s[i : j]` in **Python 3**, where
>   `(0 <=i <= j <= n)`, takes how much time in Big-O notation?

Is it O(n) or O(1) or something else?

**Edit**

**Also is there any implementation difference in slicing of a list and a string in python 3?**

Answer (score 5):

CPython implements string slicing by making a new string object containing the extracted characters.  That takes time proportional to the number of characters copied, so takes time proportional to `j-i` (the number of characters copied).

Comment: It would be really helpful if you could also provide some source of that information. Thanks

Comment: See the other answer linked to in @DYZ's comment; in the end, there's no "proof" of this short of staring at the implementation code.

Comment: It makes sense, but just for confirmation there is no implementation difference of slicing in a list and a string?

Comment: And the same answer applies to list slicing, tuple slicing, bytes slicing, bytearray slicing ...

Comment: @Manya: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/d81bea6520892e0428aec61c73e0631a69db11bb/Objects/unicodeobject.c#L14027, https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/d81bea6520892e0428aec61c73e0631a69db11bb/Objects/unicodeobject.c#L12388, https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/d81bea6520892e0428aec61c73e0631a69db11bb/Objects/unicodeobject.c#L2207

Comment: Okay and Thanks @Tim Peters. :)

Comment: The are some minor differences between string and list, e.g. `str[:]` will return the original `str`, whereas any mutable type (e.g. list) will return a complete copy.